# google analytics filter setting for cross domain tracking

Tags: html, google-analytics

Has everyone try to modify cross-domain profile with a filter to show the full domain in content reports? How long this changes will take effect?

I followed the following steps. But nothing change.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

> 1. In the Profile Settings page, click the Add Filter link.
> 2. Choose Add New Filter and provide the filter a name.
> 3. Choose Custom Filter and select Advanced on the Filter type settings.
> 4. Under Advanced settings:
>      a. FieldA should be set to Hostname 
>      b. FieldB should be set to Request URI
> 5. Set the values for both Field A and Field B to (.*), which is an expression that captures all characters.
> 6. Set the Output To --> Constructor option to Request URI and provide $A1$B1 as the value for that choice. Your reports will now show: — www.example.com/index.php — sub.example.com/more.php This will capture the www.example.com portion of your URL and include that at the beginning of your page URL in the content reports section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are not applied retroactively. All data in analytics is static. Once it goes in it can't be changed. If you setup the filter today it will start to add the hostname to the url from now on.

You can also setup a custom report that drill down from hostname to path or even one that shows both side by side. This should give you the same data, except that it is subjected to sampling if you have too much data, where the default reports are not subjected to sampling because they are pre-processed.

eg:

https://www.google.com/analytics/web/permalink?uid=c00k2_9TSNeLVakblonUZg